# Can SqlDataConnection Type Provider modify data in Oracle DB?

Tags: database, oracle, f#, type-providers

I'm thinking of using F# to connect to an Oracle 11g database. I'd like to know if it's possible to use SqlDataConnection with F# to not only have my types from the database connection but also be able to modify them.

**Context**

I have a movie database. I need to create metadata for all the movies within the database using 2 histograms: one for colour and one for texture. After I have created the column XmlData, what I'd like is to be able to iterate (or recurse cause it's F#) on the Movie collection and be able to create both histograms of the poster of the movie and then insert them in the XmlData with the norm MPEG-7.

The information would then be query with the information provided by a user using XmlProvider.

Is this possible with SQlDataConnection ? So basically, the type Movie I'd have would the field XmlData which would be set as optional would changed from a None to a Some (Data).

**UPDATE 1**

At the moment, I've been trying to connect on the Oracle 11g database through F# and the Entity framework type provider. This is currently working under C#, but I'd like to move away from C# to do it in F# and a Microsoft tutorial makes it sound really simple.

This is the code that I have to define the schema of my database in code :

```
type oracleSchema = SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  big-data.log.mtl.ca)(PORT = 1521))     (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = GTI660)));Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usernanme;Password=someRidiculousPwd",Pluralize = true>
```

What I'd like to know, I've copy pasted the connection string I was using in my C# project inside the the type provider hoping for it to work. Both SqlDataConnection & SqlEntityConnection are seen as undefined. I was trying to see if at least it could recognize the SqlDataConnection. In the nugget packages, I've added F# Data to have access to the type providers. In the source file, I've opened the following namespaces (as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/accessing-a-sql-database-entities))

```
open System.Data.Linq
open System.Data.Entity
```

I can't opened the following namespace :

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
```

And it kind of makes sense right ? Providers are located in F# Data nugget package. I should specify that I couldn't find the following extension : FSharp.Data.TypeProviders to add to the library project.

Comment: can you give a more concrete example? and also where you are stuck? from you description it sounds like you retrieve some data from a table, then write it back modifying one of the columns. That's certainly possible.

Comment: @s952163 Well, right now I'm trying to connect on Oracle using SqlEntityConnection but IntelliSense is telling me that the type is undefined. I've followed the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/accessing-a-sql-database-entities For the F# project. Although, I couldn't find the extension for type providers, but I've added the F# Data nugget package.

Comment: I don't have access to Oracle BUT, forget about Entity Framework. If you want to access Oracle with a type provider use a) just pure ADO.NET b) the [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/oracle.html). Feel free to drop by [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f) or the fsharp slack.

Comment: Oh really? I'd much rather use a type provider if possible. But as you see in my Update, SqlDataConnection is seen as undefined. I'll by the fsharp slack later. What's your username? Guess it's fsharp.slack.com?

Comment: @s952163 I need an invite from the team administrator

Comment: User name is the same. You can join F# foundation and should get an invite to the slack. Regarding the type provider, you should/can use the SQLProvider, not the one from MS. Get it via nuget I referenced in the link above. You need the .NET driver for oracle, then you also need to  `open FSharp.Data.Sql`